# 2 BPMN files get deployed with war deployment

Tags: camunda

I noticed that when I deploy my camunda project as a WAR. I see 2 deployments for the same BPMN file in Cockpit and even in the logs I see 2 deployments.

One is with the process archive 'processApplication' and another one is with the neame of the project.

The 'isScanForProcessDefinitions' setting in processes.xml is set to true.

Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you have either the processes.xml or probably your process definition (bpmn file) twice on the classpath.
Maybe in an embedded jar or in the war itself.